# Node server delay

Tags: node.js, http, server, http2

I have node js server running a script through pm2 daemon.

sometimes the server cannot be connected to on the first try, a second try and the server can be connected to perfectly.

I have now moved from http to http2 server base.

any suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you verified the application is running? Are there any network reliability issues? Are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: @Deadron no errors in the log, but i believe the issue is that node is slow to handle the very first connection or a connection that takes place long after a previous connection. thanks for the help, any ideas on how to keep the node app "aware"??